# Elasticsearch "max_file_descriptors" : -1

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the meaning of **max_file_descriptors=-1** from this ElasticSearch response? Does it mean number of open files descriptors is **unlimited**? I'm running on Windows 7.

```
http://localhost:9200/_nodes/process?pretty
```

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : {
    "N-q5umbYSGKdiFhWFuSoNA" : {
      "name" : "Lady Mandarin",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/10.201.2.219:9300]",
      "host" : "USF554",
      "ip" : "10.201.2.219",
      "version" : "1.3.2",
      "build" : "dee175d",
      "http_address" : "inet[/10.201.2.219:9200]",
      "process" : {
        "refresh_interval_in_millis" : 1000,
        "id" : 1996,
        "max_file_descriptors" : -1,
        "mlockall" : false
      }
    }
  }
}
```